# One to many too much data returned - MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select, one-to-many

I have 2 related MySQL tables in a one to many relationship.

**Customers:** cust_id, cust_name, cust_notes

**Orders:** order_id, cust_id, order_comments

So, if I do a standard join to get all customers and their orders via PHP, I return something like:

- Jack Black, jack's notes, comments about jack's 1st order
- Jack Black, jack's notes, comments about jack's 2nd order
- Simon Smith, simon's notes, comments about simon's 1st order
- Simon Smith, simon's notes, comments about simon's 2nd order

The problem is that *cust_notes* is a text field and can be quite large (a couple of thousand words). So, it seems like returning that field for every order is inneficient.

I could use *GROUP_CONCAT* and *JOINS* to return all *order_comments* on a single row BUT order_comments is a large text field too, so it seems like that could create a problem.

Should I just use two separate queries, one for the customers table and one for the orders table?

Is there a better way?

Comment: What's the purpose of this query? Are you going to list it with pagination or what?

Comment: On a PHP page, I need to show all the data for a customer and then all their associated orders. I will create some kind of paging system when orders > 20 for a given customer.

Comment: for one customer? what's the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that I only need the cust_notes field to be returned once. But, with a normal join it is returned for every associated order. This seems to be inneficient due to the size of the cust_notes field (couple of thousand words or more)

Comment: If you request only one customer's info, there is no reason to make it with single query. Just request customer info first, and then request their orders and list it below. isn't it obvious? If you need some other data representation - there can be other answers.

Comment: example of what? how to make these 2 queries with simple WHERE customer_id = num? Don't you know it already?

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have specified that I am trying to do this with one query. Sorry about that.

Comment: An. I see now. Your fears for the connection overhead are baseless. As a matter of fact, the number of queries doesn't affect connection overhead by any means. And I doubt there is any issue with connection overhead anyway. That's why once was said "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Ok, cool. If connection overhead isn't a big deal (as I thought it was), then I have made way too big of a deal about this. Thanks! Also, I haven't heard that quote before, totally true.

Comment: @emcpete if you've found your solution in any of the answers bellow, accept them by clicking on the V. You can (and should) also upvote/downvote answers. That's the way Stack Overflow's (SO) community works. Happy SO'ing!

Comment: @Frankie, I did select one, the answer right below this submitted by Col. Shrapnel. Also, I am new so the system won't let me upvote (until I reach 15 reputation).

Comment: @emcpete, you're absolutely right! My bad! Welcome to SO! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look. Your page is much like an question page on SO. A question first and answers below.
Noone bother to request it with one query!

Answers - yes, uses join, but to get names and id's only, not full user's info.
Nothing complicated.

Just use separate queries for the customer and for the list of orders

Comment: Cool, thanks. That is what I will go with. I guess connection overhead isn't a big deal. Lots of people saying something similar on this one but Col. Shrapnel was the first to answer (via commenting on the original question) so he gets the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, it is better to use two query, for a results like:

```
Jack black
   comments
   comments
   comments
   comments

Simon Smith
   comments
   comments
   comments
```

Comment: Yeah, perhaps two queries would be better. I was trying to avoid that due to the connection overhead via PHP.

Comment: @emcpete Can you submit one request with two queries and get successive result sets? http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2007/06/01/mysql-multiple-result-procs-in-php/

Comment: @emcpete are you really experience any connection problems in your app?

Comment: Hmm, I am not quite sure what you mean. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Typically we used a few different strategies.

In one case we returned multiple result sets - one set for the parents and one for all the children.  The ORDER BY was the same, so that you could easily interleave the children for each parent in the client code.

It was also possible to return multiple result sets - one for the parents and one set of children for EACH parent (we used a cursor for the outer part of this).

Another thing we used (in SQL Server) was XML so it actually returned the hierarchical form.

Comment: Yeah, multiple result sets looks very interesting. Unfortunately I am stuck with MYSQL 4 so I don't there is support for that. But for anyone else, a definite possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run two queries, one for notes and one for the customer details.

```
// this will give you orders in an efficient way
SELECT cust_id, order_id, order_comments
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN orders as o ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
LIMIT xx, yy

// this will get all details from N specific customers
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE cust_id = 'xxx' OR cust_id = 'yyy' OR cust_id = 'zzz'
```

And then **pass the second query to an array** and, as you're showing the first one, use the details from the customer that are stored in the array.

Should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I think 2 queries is the way to go. I was trying to do it with one due to php->mysql connection overhead. But apparently I was mistaken about the weight of that. Thanks!